# Is it possible to change the default window animation in Gnome Shell (preferably to fade in/out)?

Tags: gnome, window-manager, desktop-environment, gnome-shell, mutter

Instead of the default zoom in/out animations when opening and closing windows in Gnome Shell, is it possible to have a fade in/out animation? I am mostly interested in this because when opening a terminal, it stutters when loading `.zshrc`.

I know I can disable animations completely with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false`, but I rather like the animation in Gnome Shell overall (dock, overview, etc). Another solution would be if it is possible to disable window animations only for `gnome-terminal` but keep them for other applications.

Comment: I can see there are some extension that manage this on some extent for ex. https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/499/window-fade-in/ and https://github.com/rliang/gnome-shell-window-animations